# Automatically sanitize @Args in type-graphql

Tags: typegraphql

Is it possible to automatically sanitize the args?

```
...
  @Mutation(returns => Ok)
  async signup(@Args() args: args.GetSignupArgs ) {
    sanitize(args);
    const { name, email, password } = args;
    const checkUser = await this.userRepository.findOne({ email })
...
```

Comment: What are you trying to do in the sanitization step? Are you looking to do validations on the data types? Prevent SQL injection? Trim whitespace?  I imagine depending on what you're trying to do there could be different answers.

Comment: This code above works with this `class-sanitizer` library, I was wondering if `type-graphql` had a specific way to inject differently typed class libraries the same way it handles `class-validator`. What the sanitize function does is sort of irrelevant, the quest is more geared to if there is middleware between the route and this resolver that can handle this sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this by injecting a global middleware. See: https://github.com/19majkel94/type-graphql/blob/master/docs/middlewares.md